How do idealists explain our lack of consciousness when we sleep?
When we sleep, or when we are dead, we are, or atleast seem to be, not conscious. This to me is very basic evidence that consciousness supervenes on the physical, but how do idealistic philosophers explain this if consciousness is fundamental in their eyes? Note that by idealism, I mean it in a metaphysical sense: the idea that mind is crucial/fundamental to reality
What exactly is happening during sleep, or death or in general any time where we seem to not be conscious from an idealist’s perspective?

Do you remember your dreams? I often do. Have you had lucid dreams? I did when I was working at that. Have you had a blackout drinking episode? I did, in college, long ago. Consciousness doesn't end with sleep (or drinking), it changes. Meditation is going to be your very best route to getting more insight. I've consciously observed parts of my mind drifting off to sleep during meditation. "I" was still aware when the rest of my mind had lulled.

Ideas and their apperception and apprehension might not be conscious only, Leibniz introduced his ‘little thoughts’ to continue their activities in the subconscious even during sleep, not unlike modern alpha/beta waves detected during sleep cycles. In fact consciousness might be just the iceberg’s tip on top of the gigantic little thoughts and ideas. There’re other theories such as continuous stream theory suggesting non-discrete non-stopping amorphous nature of consciousness…

@DoubleKnot yes, the iceberg analogy is really useful. Naps are good, I can't tell you how many times I've easily solved a problem I was having after some sleep. 2 sleeps is usually best.

We know that some background awareness continues during sleep; sensory inputs considered important can wake us, and some of us have the experience of incorporating less important inputs into our dreams. (If I am tired enough, I can spend what feels like a half an hour in the dream trying to track down where the alarm sound is coming from before reluctantly concluding that I must be dreaming and should wake up.) Note that this is one of the ways anesthesia-induced unconsciousness differs from sleep, and as far as I know we still don't fully understand that mechanism.

"until human voices wake us, and we drown"

You can't just say "I think A is evidence of B; give me a counter-argument." You have to offer a rational argument that A is evidence of B to make it worth it for anyone to respond to.

I think you’re basically asking what is the idealist understanding of death

I vote to close this question due to lack of clarity: How do you define an idealist position? At least, please name some idealist philosophers; thanks.

@JoWehler  the OP clearly has not read any idealist thinking, including very notably not being aware of any subcontinent religions, but there isn't a clarity issue at all with the question.  He is simply raising one of the more obvious test cases against idealist philosophy of mind.  I was nearing completion of an answer that would describe the major Idealist approach to this issue when you closed the question!  As Annika said, this is about as on-target for philosophy as it is possible to be, and the question is entirely clear.  It should never have been closed.

@Dcleve I asked the OP to improve their question by clarification. After that, nothing hinders to decide about voting for reopen. - IMO it is not the task of the community to interpret, what a question could have meant, before reflecting about an answer.

There are too many different sub forms of idealism that disagree with each other about more things than they agree upon. There cannot be a correct answer unless it would treat all of them, which would be too broad.

@Annika Meta thread on it: https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6071/reopening-how-do-idealists-explain-our-lack-of-consciousness-when-we-sleep

Note that idealism posits that reality is fundamentally equivalent to mind, or that it's entirely a mental construct. Dualism (not included under idealism) may say the mind is fundamental, but that the physical is also fundamental. Just to clarify that you're indeed asking about idealism specifically.

Minds and consciousness are immensely complex, and no simple model can fit the data we have about them.
The simplest version of idealism starts with pure consciousness, and presumes that consciousness is simple and dominant.  This simple model is -- clearly not a good match to the complexity we see of different features and degrees of consciousness.  So -- idealists add complexity to the model.
The main approach I have seen from secular idealists is that the integration of the conscious expectations of the consensus of living things forge our physical universe.  Therefore, one individual going to sleep has no effect on the physical.  An example of this approach, where the integral sum of human expectations creates the physical world, is articulated in the book The Crack in the Cosmic Egg:  https://www.amazon.com/Crack-Cosmic-Egg-Constructs-Reality/dp/0892819944 A similar approach to the spiritual world is taken in much pagan thinking, where Gods do not pre-exist us, but are created by human belief.  This idea, that the Old Gods were sustained by their followers, is in the plot of many fantasy movies, such as Merlin https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139460/plotsummary/
New Age idealists often introduce the concept of an Uber-self, which is fully conscious all the time, and manipulates the physical, and a dependent self that is more closely tied to our bodies and is usually unable to manipulate the physical very well, and has incomplete memories and knowledge, and varying degrees of reduced consciousness.
The delusion that we are constrained by the limitations of the dependent self are given the term Maya in Indian subcontinent idealism.  Under Maya, we are self-deluded to think that we have limited consciousness.
Under most subcontinent idealism, plus the Perennial Philosophy, there is a Mind at Large that is aware of all, and maintains matter, when we individual minds go temporarily into lower consciousness modes.  Once more our lack of direct awareness of the Mind at Large is postulated to be a delusion/forgetfulness feature that applies to our individual minds.
Complexifying a worldview generally decreases its predictive power.  And some complexifications can vitiate predictions totally.  THAT idealism has to complexify in the face of sleep, is a minor/trivial reduction in its plausibility, so long as the resulting model is still predictive and testable.
I offer this review to show that the Perennial Philosophy is still testable.  That I think it fails these tests is a different question.  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RZY1A4EL2JOZ4?ref=pf_ov_at_pdctrvw_srp
Relative to your conclusion, that somehow sleep supports that consciousness supervenes on the physical -- no, this is a very invalid inference.
First "supervenes" is not even a testable hypothesis.  It is a vague untestable stand-in, because all identity theory clams for consciousness have failed one falsification test or another, and physicalists have been unable to date to come up with an additional complexity alternative formulation that does not fail falsification tests. Recall I noted some "complexification" makes a hypothesis untestable.  Supervenience is intended and designed to do that for physicalism.  Jaegwon Kim spelled this out in his Physicalism, or Something Near Enough.  If matter is causal for conscious, the supervenience equates to identity theory reductionism to neurons.  If something else is causal besides reduced matter, then supervenience is a stand in for emergent causally interactive dualism.  So -- per Kim's reasoning -- physicalists to reject dualism must find an identity theory that does not fail test cases.  The untestable vague fog of asserting "supervenience" is to assert untestable pseudoscience (or pseudo-philosophy), based on Popper's boundary criteria.
Second, the justification for supporting a worldview is not that some other rival model has a problem area.  Justifications for a worldview have to rely on multiple supporting evidences.  This is called consilience. And then one must show that one's preferred worldview is the superior of the two, based on Inference to Best Explanation. And when every detailed physicalist model fails test cases against consciousness and are to date unpatchable/unamendable -- then that a rival approach needs to be patched/amended in one evaluation area, is not actually support for the NON-models of physicalism at all.  Sleep, which is a subset of consciousness, is not better explained by the unpatchable physicalist non-models of consciousness than the patches needed by idealist models.
One CAN put a rationale together for physicalism over idealism, arguing based on consilience across non-consciousness aspects of our world's data, and on the IBE advantages of physicalism in non-consciousness areas in general over idealism weighting more in a comparative evaluation than any advantage idealism may have for consciousness.  And I at least might agree with that argument.
BUT -- I would then counter that one can get an even better match to consciousness data with interactive dualism than even with idealism, AND that physicalism has no advantage relative to dualism in non-consciousness areas.  And that therefore an IBE would support interactive dualism.

Idealism with the "Mind at Large" idea is basically the Matrix, which I think is self-defeating. There isn't one big star that all the other stars are under, or one big atom that all the atoms are inside, so why make that argument for awareness?

@ScottRowe I am not trying to defend MAL, maya or any of the other concepts I mentioned.  I was just trying to answer the question with what idealists say.

I liked the "immensely complex" part, and the answer has good coverage of the points.


When we sleep, or when we are dead, we are, or atleast seem to be, not conscious.

When we are asleep we are very definitely conscious. Any eeg recording would show brain activity. Whereas when you are dead or brain dead no eeg recording would show anything.
Mixing up the two is a category mistake.

What exactly is happening during sleep, or death or in general any time where we seem to not be conscious from an idealist’s perspective?

This is not a well-posed question given what I have said in the paragraph above.

OP: "What exactly is happening during sleep, or death or really anything where we seem to not be conscious from an idealist’s perspective?"
"how do idealistic philosophers explain this if consciousness is fundamental"
Descartes's "cogito ergo sum" was a significant influence on the idealist philosophers.  Here it is not 'cogito' that is fundamental but 'sum' : existence.  So, does existence disappear in sleep?
As a transcendental idealist, Immanuel Kant could lay no conception to the being of Descartes' 'sum'. So where Descartes says "cogito ergo sum", "I think therefore I am", this ground 'existence' is what Kant calls the "unconditioned necessity".  This is what doesn't disappear when consciousness sleeps.
I.e. from the Critique of Pure Reason Transcendental Dialectic — Book II:

from the totality of the conditions of thinking objects in general, in
so far as they can be given, the absolute synthetical unity of all
conditions of the possibility of things in general; that is, from
things which I do not know in their mere transcendental conception, I
conclude a being of all beings which I know still less by means of a
transcendental conception, and of whose unconditioned necessity I can
form no conception whatever. This dialectical argument I shall call
the ideal of pure reason. B 398

This existence, or 'unconditioned necessity' is the unthought 'stucture' of being. As the form of existence that grounds entities (the being of all beings), including the Self, it is prior to conditioning by thought (which determines entities), yet must be(?) there i.e. as a necessity.  It is what Heidegger calls 'Being', and he does not limit it to consciousness (or understanding, which is a mode of Being). Since it is indefinable and indeterminate he does not even limit it to death:

in the ontological analysis of Being-towards-the-end there is no
anticipation of our taking any existential stand towards death. If
"death" is defined as the 'end' of Dasein—that is to say, of
Being-in-the-world—this does not imply any ontical decision whether
'after death' still another Being is possible, either higher or lower,
or whether Dasein 'lives on' or even 'outlasts' itself and is
'immortal'. Being & Time H.
247-8


Idealism isn't necessarily restricted to one's mind, merely "the domain of ideas".
So for instance George Berkeley is one of the classic advocates for a "reality does not exist outside of the mind", but explains why things continue to exist even when we're dreaming (or nobody is watching them) by invoking the mind of God, which (since it is a divine mind and not a mortal one) may know, see, and encompass all of creation at once. Here's Three Dialogues (more readable text with some additions) which are, for whatever reason, formatted as dialogues.

Philonous: To me it is evident, for the reasons you allow of, that sensible things cannot exist otherwise than in a mind or spirit. Whence I conclude, not that they have no real existence, but that, seeing they depend not on my thought, and have an existence distinct from being perceived by me, there must be some other mind wherein they exist. As sure, therefore, as the sensible world really exists, so sure is there an infinite omnipresent Spirit, who contains and supports it.

So for Berkeley this is a bit of a dual-purpose thing. God solves the issue of why your body exists as you sleep, and your body existing while you sleep proves the existence of God.

It's just so weird that I have to include it: SEP's article on Berkeley includes this discussion in a form of limericks:

There was a young man who said God,
must think it exceedingly odd
if he finds that the tree
continues to be
when no one’s about in the Quad.

And the response:

Dear Sir, your astonishment’s odd
I am always about in the Quad
And that’s why the tree
continues to be
since observed by, Yours faithfully, God


There is no single concept of "idealism"; rather, there are different forms of it. Broadly speaking, there is critical idealism (Kant) and absolute idealism.
Strictly speaking, Kant did not advocate for critical idealism (the world is real but cannot be fully known), as he claimed, but rather a form of strong idealism. Schopenhauer, on the other hand, postulate a mix of realism and idealism, because, like Kant, he could not logically derive the "thing-in-itself." His position is therefore  inconsistent.
Hegel, contrary to what is often taught at universities, represented a form of realism. Thus, there is no single "idealism," but rather various forms based on imperfect philosophical systems.
Idealists cannot fully answer the posed question because all these systems remain conceptually flawed, which suggests a fundamental error—though this does not refute critical idealism. Realism cannot be true (see Kant), and strong idealism cannot be reconciled with this critique. However, strong idealism is not a serious philosophical movement today.
